# How to skip "no.," when using ieee biblatex style with biber?

Tags: biblatex, biber, ieee-style

Consider the bibliography file `biblio.bib`

```
@article{Sutter-TheFreeLunchIsOver,
  author={Herb Sutter},
  title={The Free Lunch Is Over: A Fundamental Turn Toward Concurrency in Software},
  journal={Dr.\ Dobb's Journal},
  year={2005},
  volume={30},
  number={3},
  month= mar
}
```

and the latex file `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Sutter-TheFreeLunchIsOver}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

No matter whether we are using the article class or the ieeetran class, a "no." without a number is printed to the PDF obtained from `pdflatex main && biber main && pdflatex main`:

[image: the output of pdflatex main && biber main && pdflatex main]

I have no idea why the number entry (`number={3}`) in the `.bib` file is ignored and whether the printing of "no." without a number is a bug or a feature. Apparently, it is hard to turn off, since the biblatex-ieee documentation also has this bug/feature as of March 2, 2017.

In any case, I'd like to avoid "no., " altogether or to have "no. 3," instead. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug of the style. The current definition in `ieee.bbx`is:

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit
  \bibstring{number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{eid}%
}
```

The `\bibstring` is wrong. It should be `\printfield`

So add the following definition to your header (after loading `biblatex`).

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{eid}%
}
```

The author is informed.

Comment: @LeonMeier: The author uploads an update. In the next few days it should be available via your package manager.